# PHP returns JSON object to jQuery ajax call.. what now?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have been reading over a lot of questions, but cant seem to find my particular problem
I have a PHP script that returns a fetch array and I encode that to JSON. I have no headers in my PHP script (I read something about that but haven't got a clue)

The PHP

```
if (mysql_num_rows($pquery) == 1) {
   $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($pquery);
   echo json_encode($result);

}
```

The jQuery

```
$('#c_search').submit(function(){
       data = ($(this).serialize());

  $.ajax({
      url: 'actions/get_company.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      success: function(text){
          alert (text);
          alert(text[1]); // not right!
          alert(text.company[0]);// not right!
      }

}).error(function(){
    alert('error');
})
return false;

})
```

The text I get back:

```
{"id":"167","company":"ZEN","street":"1 S Congress Ave","email":"zxyz@yahoo.com","state":"TX","zip":"78704","phone":"512-555-1212"}
```

How do I handle this properly so I can place each individual piece into its own variable.

Comment: Got it pegged! Thank you all... will check in 6 minutes when stack allows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data: data,
cache: false,
dataType: 'json', // <!-- indicate that the response type is JSON => not necessary if your PHP script correctly sets the Content-Type: application/json response header
success: function(text) {
    alert(text.id);
    alert(text.company);
    alert(text.street);
    alert(text.email);
    ...      
}
```

Comment: all of these answers pointed me in the right direction, as i went down the line this is the one the made simple sense and worked first. Thanks all.. up votes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dataType` to have jQuery parse the response as JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'actions/get_company.php',
    dataType: 'json',

    [..]
```

`data` will then be a normal Javascript `Object`, so you can access the fields as normal:

```
 alert (data.street);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JSON.parse()`

```
$('#c_search').submit(function(){
       data = ($(this).serialize());

  $.ajax({
      url: 'actions/get_company.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      success: function(text){
          var obj = JSON.parse(text);
          alert (text);
          alert(text[1]); // not right!
          alert(text.company[0]);// not right!
      }

}).error(function(){
    alert('error');
})
return false;

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with datatype : JSON or Use $.getJSON instead of $.ajax.

Answer (score 1):

set the `dataType` to `json` so that the json is parsed for you like

```
$.ajax({
dataType:'json',
});
```

or you can parse the json manualy by

```
$.ajax({
dataType:'json',
success:function(json){
     var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON(json);
 },
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7TzGp/4/)